# How to implement 'To' field functionality present in Windows Phone 8 inbuild message application

Tags: windows-phone-8

I need to implement functionality similar to 'To' field present in the Windows Phone 8 in build message application.

1. Whenever user wants to remove any name from 'To' field, he needs to tap on that name then one message pop up will be displayed with remove, open, copy and cancel
2. User cannot place the cursor in between of the name, once the name is ended with the semicolon

Can anyone suggest me the approach to implement this feature?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom control you would have to write. It is not delivered along the other Windows Phone Controls.

Here is a scetch of how you could achieve this: The custom control is a combination of a `TextBlock` ("To:" Field) followed by a `GridView`, Followed by a `TextBox` (Input Field).
Now at the beginning, the `GridView` has no entries and is therefore not visible. If the user selects an Email from the type ahead or closes the input by a semicolon (listen to the `KeyUp` Event of the TextBox), your control logic creates an instance of a datamodel which then holds the ID, Email Address, Name and whatever you would need. This instance is then added to an `ObservableCollection` which is bound to the `GridView`. Having the `ObservableCollection` in place will result in an automatic display of the entry in the `GridView`. Now clear the `TextBox` and be prepared for the next entry.

The rest is only layout stuff to have no borders on your `TextBox`, have the `GridView` display the Names with Semicolons etc.

Finally react on `GridView` selections with the Popup to delete or Update its content.